# Access denied in OpenSearch Serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to create a minimal working example for working with AWS OpenSearch Serverless. With the help of [this](https://youtu.be/SUVjrOKYVVk) tutorial, this is the code:

```py
import boto3
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth

host = 'onb565zzbfkjr3spn8v5.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, region)
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{
        'host': host,
        'port': 443
    }],
    http_auth = auth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

def create_index(index_name):
    index_body = {
      'settings': {
        'index': {
          'number_of_shards': 1
        }
      }
    }
    response = client.indices.create(index_name, body=index_body)
    print('\nCreating index:')
    print(response)

create_index('myindex')
```

I have performed the following steps:

1. Created an IAM user that has the policies `AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess` and `AmazonESFullAccess` (just in case). I also added two inline policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "aoss:APIAccessAll",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "aoss:DashboardsAccessAll",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(for some reason, the latter two permissions are not shown when I create a collection)

2. Executed `aws configure` to provide the keys and the region.
3. Created a collection with the rule for `Public` access, the IAM user as the selected principal, and all accesses enabled.

Despite all this, I get 403 (Access denied) when trying to create an index. What could I be missing?

**UPDATE** I have now asked the same question in the [AWS community](https://repost.aws/questions/QU0Khakx3TR_mjnlh5STDmzA/access-denied-403-when-creating-an-index-in-opensearch-serverless).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the service name to the request signer:

```py
auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, region, 'aoss')
```

I think the credentials you're retrieving are for the wrong service. Looking at the source of [`opensearchpy.AWSV4SignerAuth()`](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/blob/3eba72c32055033c8689809a514a10c40ac24a18/opensearchpy/helpers/signer.py#L78) the search is defaulted to `es` (ElasticSearch) which is incorrect for OpenSearchServerless.

Slight aside - I found this pretty confusing because the service is keyed as `opensearchserverless` rather than `aoss` in boto3. I'm surprised that wasn't solved before this was made generally available a year ago.